# Failing to retrieve data from subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, mean, angular5

I'm trying to retrieve data from a subscribed item but it doesn't change the currentMemberDetail: Member object, it remains undefined.

```
public currentMemberDetail: Member;

constructor(public authService: AuthService,
    public memberService: MemberService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {

    this.memberService.getOne(this.authService.currentUser)
        .subscribe(m => {this.currentMemberDetail = m; console.log(m)});
}

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.memberService.getOne(this.authService.currentUser)
        .subscribe(m => {this.currentMemberDetail = m; console.log(m)});

    console.log(this.currentMemberDetail);

}
```

Here is what i get from console logs

Member {_id: "5a44bdb416ff3e115c0d732a", pseudo: "admin", password: "admin", profile: "I'm the administrator of the site!", birthdate: undefined, …}

m has the object but I can't parse it to currentMemberDetail and it remains undefined.

I've tried ngOnInit and inside the constructor.

Any solutions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
console.log(this.currentMemberDetail);
```

It is outside of the subscribe. Because `.getOne` is asynchronous, the line above is getting logged before it has been set

If you change the subscribe to:

```
.subscribe(m => {this.currentMemberDetail = m; console.log(this.currentMemberDetail)});
```

You should see it has been set.

Comment: Thanks, The goal here is to retrieve the data from m to currentMemberDetail so I can use it to display information on the .component.html
How can parse the data?
<h1>{{ currentMemberDetail.pseudo }}'s profile</h1>

Comment: What do you mean parse it? It should already be parsed from JSON if that's what you mean... What bit is not working?

Comment: the currentMemerDetail is still undefined when I try to display information inside the html component.
MemberDetailComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pseudo' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (MemberDetailComponent.html:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js:13113)[...]

Comment: Okay, I follow. Change it to `<h1>{{ currentMemberDetail?.pseudo }}'s profile</h1>` which uses the null-safe operator. That way, when currentMemberDetail is null or undefined, it won't throw an error, but once it's been set it should work

Comment: It's working perfectly. The problem now is that I don't understand why it can read it but still shows an error undefined message

Comment: So it's still displaying an error message? Any nchace you can create a Plunkr or StackBlitz?

Comment: It's going to be too long. Thank you anyway mate! I can at least continue :)